# Crashlytics Error:(11, 0) Plugin with id 'io.fabric' not found compile lib

Tags: crashlytics

I am getting the error,

> Error:(11, 0) Plugin with id 'io.fabric' not found

when trying to run crashlytics on my project.

Comment: I have same problem & find one solution (http://stackoverflow.com/a/29045437/4025692)

Answer (score 28):

I faced the same issue, when tried to use Fabric plugin for android studio(automated code generation by plugin).[I followed this documentation also.](https://docs.fabric.io/android/fabric/integration.html#manual-setup)

And finally, I could see there were some missed lines in build.gradle.

So this is the top level project build.gradle

```
 // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
            classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        }
    }
apply plugin: 'java'
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        }
    }
```

and this is the build.gradle for app module

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

    android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "your application package name"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5"
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

and at last "clean build" and all was set for me.

Comment: This answer has a lot of unrelated stuff in it and could be shortened down to the point that actually answers the question (which is probably the "dependencies" block)

Comment: +1 for `maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }` in buildscript.repositories (top level build.gradle)

Comment: instead of `compile`, use `implementation`

Comment: I forgot to add:   `classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'`

Answer (score 14):

I ended up creating an empty project and using the plugin on it and then I compared the gradle file and realized that this was not being added

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}
```

Comment: Could not find any matches for io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+ as no versions of io.fabric.tools:gradle are available.

Answer (score 6):

in your project gradle file:

```
buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
            classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        }
    }
apply plugin: 'java'
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        }
    }
```

in your app gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

    android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "your application package name"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5"
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nagashree,that was the original answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You just forget to add below mentioned line in Project level gradle file.

```
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
```

Also please add below mentioned line in dependencies (in project level gradle file)

```
classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.26.1'
```

Comment: Is it different than the other answers here?

Answer (score 2):

I think you lost "google()" in repositories of buildscript.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have faced this issue while working with Android + Cordova + Angularjs Hybrid project.

```
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
```

By commenting this line at the path /app/build.gradle solved the issue.

Hope it helps someone!!