# Error:(18, 0) Plugin with id 'io.fabric' not found

Tags: android

Fabric was successfully working on my project. On some day suddenly it started giving me error "`Error:(18, 0) Plugin with id 'io.fabric' not found`". I checked everything, but it was correctly integrated. Please help and give solution

Outer build.gradle

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {

        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
```

Inner build.gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

    repositories {
       maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.7@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

   }

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Crashlytics Error:(11, 0) Plugin with id 'io.fabric' not found compile lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27580249/crashlytics-error11-0-plugin-with-id-io-fabric-not-found-compile-lib)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add classpath in outer build.gradle file like this

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}
```

Complete outer build.gradle file look like below

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
  }

  dependencies {
    // These docs use an open ended version so that our plugin
    // can be updated quickly in response to Android tooling updates

    // We recommend changing it to the latest version from our changelog:
    // https://docs.fabric.io/android/changelog.html#fabric-gradle-plugin

    // Add more class path here as per your project requirement 
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes set like this. this is the solution to resolve this error.

Comment: I have added all these lines along with apply plugin: 'io.fabric'.But this line is giving error.

Comment: Post ur outer build.gradle file in question please

Comment: @LavekushAgrawal I have shared gradle. Please check

Comment: Due you using it in some module, and using this to other project?

Comment: am using it in project