# I am trying to run my ionic angular firebase app in android studio but when running ionic capacitor run android i get all kinds of error

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, capacitor

When I run this code:

```
ionic capacitor run android --verbose
```

I get this error:

```
 Running Gradle build - failed!
> Configure project :app
[capacitor]         WARNING:: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
[capacitor]         It will be removed in version 7.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
[capacitor]         For more information, see http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html.
[capacitor]         google-services.json not found, google-services plugin not applied. Push Notifications won't work
[capacitor]         WARNING:: Using flatDir should be avoided because it doesn't support any meta-data formats.

[capacitor]         > Configure project :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins
[capacitor]         WARNING:: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
[capacitor]         It will be removed in version 7.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
[capacitor]         For more information, see http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html.
[capacitor]         WARNING:: Using flatDir should be avoided because it doesn't support any meta-data formats.

  * What went wrong:
[capacitor]         A problem occurred evaluating project ':capacitor-cordova-android-plugins'.
[capacitor]         > Plugin with id 'io.fabric' not found.
[capacitor]         Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess capacitor.

        capacitor.cmd run android --target Pixel_3a_API_28 exited with exit code 1. 
ionic version 6.16.3 
 "@capacitor/core": "3.0.2",
"cordova-plugin-firebase": "^2.0.5",
  "firebase": "^8.6.8"
```

Comment: I think they key message in your output is `Plugin with id 'io.fabric' not found.`. Does this answer your question? [Crashlytics Error:(11, 0) Plugin with id 'io.fabric' not found compile lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27580249/crashlytics-error11-0-plugin-with-id-io-fabric-not-found-compile-lib)

Comment: Try `ionic capacitor build android --verbose` and see if it installs the packages in Gradle.